# Image Carousel widget in Wordpress elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

tabIndex issue with active state of slide.

Hello Guys. I had an issue. I have elementor Image Carousel. For accessibility I need to set .swiper-pagination-bullet always have attribute tabIndex="0".
But always when active element changes, attribute tabIndex="0" adding to active one and delete from others. I was trying to do it with Javascript. But nothing helps. Do You have any suggestions guys?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.